# FormatDateTime - how to display nanoseconds?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to display DB2 Timestamp which is of the form:

> 2007-09-24-15.53.37.2162474.

***FormatDateTime()*** allows only displaying milliseconds.
How can I display full Timestamp string as defined in DB2?

My code looks like that now:

```
StringGrid1.Cells[i, query.RecNo] :=  FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd.hh.mm.ss.zzz',
                                      query.Fields[i].AsDateTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ohhh! I was focused on the code instead of SQL.

Just used:

```
SELECT char(TIMESTAMP) FROM table;
```

and then:

```
StringGrid1.Cells[i, query.RecNo] := query.Fields[i].AsString;
```